# Formula to equal cell but if a different cell also has a value equal that cell instead

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a formula to equal a cell if it has a value but if a different cell has a value then equal that cell instead also need it to have text at the end of it

Here is an example.

If E11 has value and F11 also has value =F11

If E12 has value and F12 does not have value =E12

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this: `=IF(F11="",IF(E11="","",E11&" -"&$E$10),F11&" -"&$F$10)`

(In cell C11, and then copy the formula down)

Answer (score 1):

You could check "isblank":

```
=if(isblank(f11),e11,f11)
```

This checks if F11 is blank, if it is, then you pull the value from e11, if F11 is not blank (ie a value), it gives you F11.

If you want to also check e11 for blank, you can expand it to this:

```
=if(isblank(f11),if(isblank(e11),"",e11),f11)
```

which just nests the check on both cells.
;)